# Prevent application from changing Windows keyboard layout

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-layout

My only installed keyboard layout is Italian but when I open a specific application which is in english, **it automatically adds and changes my keyboard layout to English (USA)**. No keyboard shortcuts or hot-keys involved.

If I switch back to Italian, as soon as I click somewhere in the application, the keyboard switches back to ENG.

If I navigate to the windows installed keyboards, only Italian is showed. Even in the registry preload keyboards, only 410 (ITA) is loaded.

How can I block this behavior?

I tried ALL the solutions found on google, but not had the desired effect.

OS: Windows 10 build 2004

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution mixing solutions found on internet:

1. I **added the language pack ENG United States** (minimum size) to the
   languages on my PC.
2. Then I went to the keyboards of that language. **I** **installed the
   Italian qwerty keyboard and uninstalled the English keyboard**.
3. Now even if the application automatically changes to English, the
   keyboard layout is still Italian.

How it will help some.